# Configurable head with chameleon load

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal, template-metal

When using chameleon, I can replace element from a base template using the concept of slot. Where you define a slot and fill it using another tag. As there is no container element in head, how can one add elements to head ? :

The Layout file

```
<html>
<head>
  <div metal:define-slot="extra_head"></div>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

The content template that need to specify extra head.

```
<html metal:use-macro="load: main.pt">
<div metal:fill-slot="extra_head">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example/script.js"></script>
</div>
...
</html>
```

This gets rendered in :

```
<html>
<head>
  <div metal:fill-slot="extra_head">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example/script.js"></script>
  </div>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

But there's no container tag in head so how can one define a slot to add stuff in the head ?

Answer (score 3):

There's an alternative to using `tal:omit-tag` (which I'm finding annoyingly confusing - more than once I spent many minutes trying to figure out why a certain tag does not appear in the output when it's clearly present in the template, only to find `tal:omit-tag` neatly tucked in the far corner): if you use xml tags with `tal:` and `metal:` namespaces they won't appear in the output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <metal:my-slot define-slot="extra_head"></metal:my-slot>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

and in the child template:

```
<metal:template use-macro="load: main.pt">
    <metal:any-descriptive-name fill-slot="extra_head">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example/script.js"></script>
    </metal:any-descriptive-name>
    ...
</metal:template>
```

Note how the template becomes much more readable and self-descriptive and does not contain weird things such as a `<div>` inside `<head>` :)

You also can omit `tal:` and `metal:` prefixes on attributes when using namespaced tags, so

```
<h1 tal:condition="..." tal:content="..." tal:omit-tag="">Hi there! Bogus content for added confusion!</h1>
```

becomes

```
<tal:greeting condition="..." content="..." />
```

Comment: I bumped you up because I find disappearing div's to be confusing.  The namespace tag alternative is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the tag one has to use tal:omit-tag :

In the content template, use :

```
<html metal:use-macro="load: main.pt">
<div metal:fill-slot="extra_head" tal:omit-tag="">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example/script.js"></script>
</div>
...
</html>
```

The div is not part of the result. [Read the doc](http://chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#tal-omit-tag).